# How to Execute multiple commands in Process

Tags: c#, process

I have a list of a thousand items, Each of these items must be checked by the CMD.exe, With the help of the following code, I can check an item by CMD

```
  var p = new Process
 {
   StartInfo =
   {
     UseShellExecute = false,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     FileName = "cmd",
     Arguments = $"list {Id}"
   }};
   p.Start();
   var _Data = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

But the question is, I want all of these items to be checked quickly by CMD, I'm currently doing this as follows

```
foreeach(var item in list)
{
     var p = new Process
     {
       StartInfo =
       {
         UseShellExecute = false,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         CreateNoWindow = true,
         FileName = "cmd",
         Arguments = $"list {item}"
       }};
       p.Start();
       var _Data = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

But it takes a long time to do this

Comment: I beg to suggest you are probably going the wrong way about this altogether. This seems to be a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect standard input and use a StreamWriter to write to it:

```
Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("mysql -u root -p");
            sw.WriteLine("mypassword");
            sw.WriteLine("use mydb;");
        }
    }
```